# Can I help Clint woo Emily?

Tags: stardew-valley

Clint the blacksmith is clearly smitten with Emily, my sister-in-law. Is there anyway to get the two of them together?

Answer (score 3):

As you foster a better relationship with Emily and Clint, Clint will approach you in several ways to help act on the crush he has on Emily.

I have Emily and Clint maxed at 10 hearts, and I can say that the following has happened up until Fall of Year 2:

1) Clint asks for advice in speaking to women as the MC seems to be doing fairly well in this regard*. This scene occurs in the Saloon and any option used in the advice proves comedic.

2) Clint recruits you to be a delivery-person to give Emily an amethyst on his behalf.

*- This first event occurred around 4/10 hearts with Clint and 6+ hearts with most of the female marriage candidates. I'm not sure if the dialogue changes for a female main character (MC).

I have already tied the knot with Leah, and I have yet to see any other NPCs develop their 'natural' relationship.

There are some interesting dialogue entries from Emily regarding how lonely Clint must be at his shop though, so I suppose he might be striking while the iron is hot.

Comment: Those events are solely dependent on your heart level with Clint

Comment: Can you confirm this is the case? The dialogue Clint uses (the MC being very popular) seems misleading, but almost all other dialogue heart requirements are not as complex.

Comment: I got the second event despite having a very low relationship with Clint, currently only 1 heart, but it was probably at 0 hearts at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Clint and Emily never get together, and Clint's attempted courtship ends when he asks her out. She accepts, and then there is no further development. Since Emily is planned as a marriage candidate for the player in the next update, it's highly unlikely that the two of them will ever end up together in the future. All marriage candidates up to this point have remained single for the duration of the game if the player doesn't choose them.

Answer (score -1):

I have Clint at 10 hearts, and just viewed a cutscene where he asks Emily out on a date ;) Not sure if it's the 8 heart scene or the 10 heart scene though.

This is in Winter - actually the last day of the first year.

Comment: where did the scene take place?